# Change taskbar name of flutter app on windows

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop, flutter-windows

I have a very simple problem, but did not find any solution.
I wrote a flutter app for windows desktop. When I launch it, the name in the taskbar is shown as "A new Flutter project." How can I change this string? Of course I already searched all occurences of this string and renamed them to my demands, but it did not change anything:

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot above, I was able to change the icon of the app.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: how did you change the launcher icon for the taskbar and title bar thanks appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. `VALUE "FileDescription", "A new Flutter project."` in file **Runner.rc** file (in windows/runner folder) is not updated when **description:** parameter changed in **pubspec.yaml** file,
2. old file description cashed in windows registry (under **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache**) and is not updated when first issue fixed manually.

As a workaround you can remove old entry from registry (named like **<path to your project>\build\windows\runner\Debug\app.exe.FriendlyAppName**) and file description will be updated on next launch.

Comment: where exactly do i get the old entry is it inside my project folder? i cant see build

Comment: @Zuuu __build__ folder is created by `flutter build windows` command.

Comment: thats true, i understand now